# How to remove SubView from Scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

How do I remove selected scrollview blureffect

create scrollView

```
 for i in 0 ... totalPage {

        let cardView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("cardView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView

        cardView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * CardScroll.frame.size.width, y: CardScroll.frame.origin.y, width: CardScroll.frame.size.width, height: CardScroll.frame.size.height)

        let blureffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)

        blureffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blureffect)
        blureffectView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * CardScroll.frame.size.width, y: CardScroll.frame.origin.y, width: CardScroll.frame.size.width, height: CardScroll.frame.size.height)

        CardScroll.addSubview(cardView)
        CardScroll.addSubview(blureffectView)

    }
```

doubleTap action remove blureffect

```
func doubleTapped() {
    let pageNumber = CardPage.currentPage

    blureffectView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(pageNumber) * CardScroll.frame.size.width, y: CardScroll.frame.origin.y, width: CardScroll.frame.size.width, height: CardScroll.frame.size.height)

    blureffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: you need to add doubleTap action for all view in loop.

Comment: @KKRocks

let cardView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("cardView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))

CardScroll.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

This code write in loop but remove blur only last scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following below blureffectView.frame"

```
 blureffectView.tag = i ; // Set tag for every view you are adding on scrollview
```

Add action as following

```
func doubleTapped(sender:UIButton!){ // Pass sender as UIButton so you can get tag here 

   for subview in scrollView.subviews{ // Loop thorough ScrollView view hierarchy 
       if subview is UIVisualEffectView && subview.tag == sender.tag { // Check if view is type of VisualEffect and tag is equal to the view clicked
           subview.removeFromSuperview()
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: for subview in CardScroll.subviews {
            if subview is UIVisualEffectView && subview.tag == pageNumber {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
                blureffectView.removeFromSuperview()
         }
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
UIView.perform(.delete, on: CardScroll, options: [], animations: { 

         }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am resolved this problem

```
for subview in CardScroll.subviews { if subview is UIVisualEffectView && subview.tag == pageNumber { subview.removeFromSuperview() blureffectView.removeFromSuperview() } }
```